# Twitter card validator cannot validate my secured url

Tags: http, ssl, twitter, https, twitter-card

The Twitter card validator is able to validate http://my domain.com which doesn't link up with my files well because I've added "s" to the "http" in my base URL, but is unable to validate https://my domain.com. the https://my domain.com is my custom domain which has an SSL installed. I don't know why it's not been validated. Anytime I try it gives me errors: Fetching the page failed because of other errors and Unable to render Card preview.

Please any guide will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Twitter troubleshooting post](https://twittercommunity.com/t/card-error-unable-to-render-or-no-image-read-this-first/62736):

> if you see a validator message about Fetching the page failed because
> other errors or similar, check your SSL configuration. The certificate
> and server name must match (or be aliased to match) due to Java
> security constraints.

There's [more detail](https://twittercommunity.com/t/error-fetching-the-page-failed-because-ssl-handshake-error/30204/10) on the Twitter forum. You'll need to use a site such as ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to check the quality of your setup.